# Why does an if then statement turn into #VALUE! after closing and reopening the Excel file?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a somewhat large nested if then statement in a cell, which turns into #VALUE! after I save, close, and reopen the file. The if then statement is

`=IF(H2="$0.10/$0.25",O2/0.25,IF(H2="$0.25/$0.50",O2/0.5,IF(H2="$0.50/$1",O2/1,IF(H2="$1/$1",O2/1,IF(H2="$1/$2",O2/2,IF(H2="$1/$3",O2/3,IF(H2="$2/$3",O2/3,IF(H2="$2/$5",O2/5,IF(H2="$3/$5",O2/5,IF(H2="$5/$5",O2/5,IF(H2="$5/$10",O2/10,IF(H2="$10/$20",O2/20,IF(H2="$10/$25",O2/25,IF(H2="$20/$40",O2/40,IF(H2="$25/$50",O2/50)))))))))))))))`

To give some context, the value of H2 is different stakes in a poker game. For example, $1/$2 means that for every hand one person puts in $1 and the adjacent players puts in $2 before seeing their cards. The values $1/$2 are called the small and big blinds, respectively. A common way to track results is to convert all monetary values, with units $, into the units of big blind.

The statement gives no errors and outputs the correct value, in units of big blind, depending on the stakes, but after closing and reopening the cells containing the formula display #VALUE!.

I googled what the problem is and read that you can have a maximum of 64 nested functions, which is okay since I believe I only have 16. I also thought that there might be problem with cell formatting. For instance cell O2 has cell format currency, whereas the cell containing this nested if then statement has cell format general. I tested this idea on a separate sheet (same file) and it didn't cause the same error.

The version I have is 2011 running on a macbook.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The problem is in cell **O2,** If it is not a *number* you will get the error you are seeing.

Comment: By number, do you mean when I do format cells I need to chose number or that cell O2 has non numeric values in it? I ask this because there are numerical values in cell O2, but its format is currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce this problem in windows excel 2010. My suggestion is to simplify the formula and try if the problem still occurs. You can do it this way:

```
=O2/MID(H2,FIND("$",H2,2)+1,LEN(H2))
```

Find the second "$", extract the text after it (big blind) and divide O2 by it.

Comment: Thank you very much for finding a much simpler formula. Moreover, your formula works with no errors.